# Print the map of a country with the weirdest code possible

Tags: popularity-contest, ascii-art

It can be in any language, plus the map must be in the output only **not in the source code**.

This is my first question here, so please feel free to edit it. Also, there might be some rules about scoreboard which I'm not familiar how to put it here.

Cheers!

Comment: Questions that ask to do a task in creative or odd way tend not to fare well here. Creativity is better gotten by constraints and challenges rather than outright asking for it. I'd suggest trying some of the existing questions to get a feel for the site before posting your own.

Answer (score 17):

### Vatican

In CJAM:

```
46c
```

You can test it [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=46c)

Comment: lol​​​​​​​​​​​​